# Second Order Diff Eq with ode45 in Matlab

Tags: matlab, ode

So I need to solve x''(t) = -x(t)^p  with initial conditions x(0)= 0  and v(0) = x'(0) = v_o = 1.
The value of the parameter p is 1.

This is what I have:

```
function [t, velocity, x] = ode_oscilation(p)

y=[0;0;0];
    % transform system to the canonical form

    function y = oscilation_equation(x,p)
        y=zeros(2,1);
        y(1)=y(2);
        y(2)=-(x)^p;
        %  to make matlab happy we need to return a column vector
        % so we transpose (note the dot in .')
        y=y.'; 
    end

    tspan=[0, 30]; % time interval of interest

    [t,velocity,x] = ode45(@oscilation_equation, tspan, 1); 

    t = y(:,1);
    xposition=y(:,3);
    velocity=y(:,2); 

end
```

and this is the error message I receive:

> > ode_oscillation(1)
> >     Error using odearguments (line 91)
> >     ODE_OSCILLATION/OSCILATION_EQUATION must return a
> >     column vector.

Error in ode45 (line 114)
[neq, tspan, ntspan, next, t0, tfinal, tdir, y0, f0,
odeArgs, odeFcn, ...

Error in ode_oscillation (line 17)
    [t,velocity,x] = ode45(@oscilation_equation, tspan,1);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a few things going wrong here. First, from `help ode45`:

> ode45  Solve non-stiff differential equations, medium order method.
>
> ```
> [TOUT,YOUT] = ode45(ODEFUN,TSPAN,Y0) with TSPAN = [T0 TFINAL] integrates 
> the system of differential equations y' = f(t,y) from time T0 to TFINAL 
> with initial conditions Y0.
> ```

Note that `ode45` expects a function `f(t,y)`, where `size(t) == [1 1]` for time and `size(y) == [1 N]` or `[N 1]` for solution values. Your `oscilation_equation` has the order of input arguments inverted, and you input a constant parameter `p` instead of time `t`.

Also, the initial conditions `Y0` should have the same size as `y`; so `size(y0) == [N 1]` or `[1 N]`. You just have `1`, which is clearly causing errors.

Also, your output arguments `t`, `xposition` and `velocity` will be completely ignored and erroneous, since `y` is **not set as output argument** from `ode45`, and most of all, their names do not correspond to `ode_oscilation`'s output arguments. Also, their order of extracting from columns of `y` is incorrect.

So, in summary, change everything to this:

```
function [t, v, x] = ode_oscilation(p)

    % initial values
    y0 = [0 1];           

    % time interval of interest
    tspan =[0 30]; 

    % solve system 
    [t,y] = ode45(@(t,y) [y(2); -y(1)^p], tspan, y0);

    % and return values of interest
    x = y(:,1);
    v = y(:,2);

end
```